# Validation rules : error not seen in custom VF page

Tags: visualforce, validation-rule

I've a validation rule which works fine for the field in standard page but the error message is not displayed for the created custom VF page for opportunities - the same field is referred in the VF page.

Please can you advise if anything needs to be amended in the custom VF page for displaying the error message?

Comment: you may need to use `apex:inputField` in VF page

Comment: Check if you have pagemessages tag?

Comment: @ Ratan - I'm using apex:inputfield only

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - where should i have this tag?

Comment: vf code? The `apex:pageMessages` tag can go pretty much anywhere. I usually place it just under the `apex:page` tag.

Comment: Where you need error message.If you wish message at field level and not at top use apex inputfield

Answer (score 1):

1) Add the <**apex:pageMessages**/> tag to your page. (This is the container that displays any error messages if present)

2)Surround your DML call with try {} catch(DMLException e) {} (When you catch the exception you won't get redirected to the error pages, but salesforce will automatically create a "**PageMessage**" for the validation failure.

Comment: You need to rerender your `pageMessages` tag if the save fails.